# Table with rows and columns in Objective-C for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, multiple-columns

How can I implement a table with rows and columns in Objective-C? I need to show a timetable: columns for week's day and rows for hours. I have no idea. `TableView` makes rows. Would `UICollectionView` be right for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITableView`. But instead of using the default `UITableViewCell`, you have to create a custom cell with 7 labels equally spacing horizontally. Then you add 24 rows, each for one hour. And I think that's all you need, simple and straight forward.

Comment: I have to set constraints for the labels programmatically, right?

Comment: That's if you made the custom cell programmatically, if you used a xib file that contains your custom cell, you'd then apply your constraints there

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli, as the comments above. It depends on how you want to do it, either way is okay.

Comment: And if I want to display columns lines?

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli, Option 1: you can do with 6 UIView in between the 7 labels and set the colour and width to the UIView to whatever look you want them to be. Option 2: you could set the background colour for the labels and leave some space between the labels, and set the background colour of the table view cell to some other colour. Option 3 (not recommended): set the background image of the table view cell as a image with 6 vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you want to eventually display it.  What I usually do is create an array ( or two, or three if needed) and then pull from that when I want to display parts of it.  The reason I said I might need one or two is that one might be for strings and another might be for for integers or float values.  It all depends on the situation and you have to make sure you keep them synchronized programmatically.

Comment: I want to display it with a normal table multi-column with horizontal and vertical lines separating each cell from others