# Creating a Pitch n Putt scoring card using Swift - UI design

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Firstly, thank you for reading my question. I am always in complete awe and inspired by the knowledge I find on this site.

I have a Swift coding question and I'd appreciate any feedback before I get too deep into using this approach.

I am writing a Pitch and Putt scoring card for iPhones using Swift and this is my very first iOS application.

I've manually created a number of stack views with text fields inside. I will apply values to these fields and hide/show based on the number of players in the game.

I've noticed the operations within Xcode are beginning to run very slowly as I add more stack views.

Is this the best approach to developing this type of application?

I wondered if I could create the entire UI using code but from what I've researched this probably isn't easily achievable.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Dono

[image: UI Design]

[image: running UI]

Comment: Why not use a tableview and add rows based on the number of players.

Comment: Hey Paulw, is it possible to add columns to tableviews? I was under the impression they are single value only.

Comment: Each row would be the stackview that you have currently

Comment: Hi Paul, I've left off the player names, but the players score runs from top to bottom. I think I see what you're saying, I have my text fields within a tableview and that will take care of scrolling and give me some cool horizontal lines for easier reading.

Comment: @Dono, you cannot get columns from the UITableView directly. But you could create multiple labels in a row to achieve the same effects. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324786/table-with-rows-and-columns-in-objective-c-for-ios/33325217#33325217) for more.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Thank you for the reply. My next question is, what advantages do I have using a UITableView over just adding buttons directly to the ViewController as in my attached images? I apologise if this is a stupid question and thank you in advance for any reply. PS, the link you provided was great, thank you.

Comment: @Dono, `UITableView` helps you make the rows, so that you don't have to create that many buttons. You just need to create one table row and that is it. Doesn't it sound a lot less work to you? And what if you want to have more columns in the future, then it is a pain in the ass to make the adjustment from your view. What's more, you get the scrolling vertically for free by using table view, nice and neat.

Comment: @Dono, oh, one more thing. I notice that you mention it is running slow after many stack views. With UITableView, you won't have this problem because the TableViewCells are reused.